# Incorrect syntax near '=' Error CASE Statement

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have tried to add these case statements ,(CASE WHEN adj.adjcat = 'WRITE_OFF' THEN adj.amt) as 'WriteOff' to my code I am getting an incorrect sytax near ')' error.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 18

What I want to happen is if the field adj.adjcat is write_off then put the value from adj.amt in the column WriteOff 
With the following code:

```
SELECT 
ar.UCI
,ar.reportmonth
,(case when ar.transagebucket < 1 then '0_30'
    when ar.transagebucket = 1 then '31_60'
    when ar.transagebucket = 2 then '61_90'
    when ar.transagebucket = 3 then '91_120'
    when ar.transagebucket = 4 then '121_150'
    when ar.transagebucket = 5 then '151_180'
    else 'Over180' end) as AgeBucket
,ar.PatName as PatientName
,ar.AcctNu as AccountNumber
,Convert (varchar(10),ar.dos,101) as Svc_Date
,ar.cptdisplay
,(ins.insdesc+ ' - ' +ins.insmne) as Insurance
,Sum(ar.chgamt) as ChgAmt
,ISNULL(Sum(pmt.pmtamt),0) as PmtAmt
,(CASE WHEN adj.adjcat = 'WRITE_OFF' THEN adj.amt) as 'WriteOff'
,(CASE WHEN adj.adjcat = 'DEBIT' THEN adj.amt) as 'Debit'
,(CASE WHEN adj.adjcat = 'ADMIN_ADJ' THEN adj.amt) as 'AdminAdj'    
,ISNULL((ar.curbal),0) as CurBal
FROM 
rpt_dat_ARDetail ar 
LEFT JOIN rpt_dat_PmtDetail pmt ON ar.clntid = pmt.clntid 
AND ar.AcctNu =    pmt.AcctNu    
and ar.dos = pmt.dos and ar.reportmonth = pmt.reportmonth and ar.chgamt = pmt.chgamt 
and ar.curbal = pmt.curbal 
LEFT JOIN rpt_dat_AdjustmentDetail adj ON ar.clntid = adj.clntid 
AND ar.aid = adj.aid AND ar.dos = adj.dos
INNER JOIN rpt_dic_Ins ins ON ar.insmne = ins.insmne AND ar.clntid = ins.clntid
```

Comment: You missed `end` or `else <something> end`

Answer (score 2):

You are missing an `END`. Also you should avoid `'single quote'` aliases and use `[square brackets]` instead:

```
(CASE WHEN adj.adjcat = 'WRITE_OFF' THEN adj.amt END) as [WriteOff]
```

Answer (score 1):

There should be

```
(CASE WHEN adj.adjcat = 'WRITE_OFF' THEN adj.amt END) as 'WriteOff'
```

OR

```
(CASE WHEN adj.adjcat = 'WRITE_OFF' THEN adj.amt ELSE '' END) as 'WriteOff'
```

instead of

```
(CASE WHEN adj.adjcat = 'WRITE_OFF' THEN adj.amt) as 'WriteOff'
```

The same for `Debit` and `AdminAdj`.